# lightswitch datagrid hightlight selected row

Tags: c#, datagrid, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a datagrid in Lightswitch on a screen and I use it to select the project manager, the problem is that when you click on the name, then click out and the datagrid looses focus, using the cosmopolitan theme it doesn't give any indication which row is selected.

I intend eventually to write a custom theme (v2 maybe), but for now can i override this behavior in code just for this one screen? Change the highlight code for an item? I put an event handler on the 'selected item changed' but then there is no exposed item for selecteditem.background only rows.background which sets the background for all rows.

Here is my event code:

```
this.FindControl("controlname").ControlAvailable += (s, e) =>
        {
            ((Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Implementation.Controls.BaseDataGridControl)e.Control).SelectionChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler(possibleManagersChangedHandler);
        };
```

and here is the code in the possibleManagersChangedHandler

```
this.FindControl("controlname").ControlAvailable += (s, e2) =>
        {
            System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush gridBGBrush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush();
            gridBGBrush.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 170, 23);
            ((Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Implementation.Controls.BaseDataGridControl)e2.Control).RowBackground = gridBGBrush;
        };
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks